# Semigroup action generalized (relations instead of functions)

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, semigroups

If with every element of a (semi)group is associated a function, it is basically called a (semi)group action.

What if with each element of a semigroup is associated a relation? That is, formally, what if we would have a semigroup together with its homomorphism to to a semigroup of all relations on a set? Does this concept have a name? What are some of its interesting properties?

Answer (score 1):

If this homomorphism is injective, this is a semigroup of relations (and a transformation semigroup in the case of functions). In the general case, if you have a homomrphism $f$ from a semigroup $S$ to the semigroup of relations on a set $Q$, then $f$ defines an action on $\mathcal{P}(Q)$ defined, for each $P \in {\cal P}( Q)$ by
$$
P \cdot s = \{q \in Q \mid \text{there exists $p \in P$ such that $(p, q) \in f(s)$}\}
$$